Sqlite3 Calculating yearly savings from accounts table
I am trying to compute savings (ie, Income - Expenses) from my accounts table which has records like this.
____________________________
| Type     | Amount | Year |
____________________________
| Income   |   x    | 2024 |
| Expenses |   y    | 2024 |
____________________________

create table if not exists HouseAccounts (Type text, Amount integer, Year integer);

The query I am using is as below:
select YearlyIncome - YearlyExpenses as Savings, YearlyIncome, YearlyExpenses, Year 
from (
select sum(Amount) as YearlyExpenses, 0 as YearlyIncome, Year from HouseAccounts where Type='Expenses' and Year between 2015 and 2024 group by Year 
union all
select sum(Amount) as YearlyIncome, 0 as YearlyExpenses, Year from HouseAccounts where Type='Income' and Year between 2015 and 2024 group by Year
)
group by Year

This results in:
__________________________________________________
| Savings | YearlyIncome | YearlyExpenses | Year |
__________________________________________________
 -96772          0             96772        2015
 -264187         0            264187        2016
 -468902         0            468902        2017
 -387820         0            387820        2018
 -413228         0            413228        2019
 -396278         0            396278        2020
 -445823         0            445823        2021
 -438182         0            438182        2022
 -375324         0            375324        2023
 -472977         0            472977        2024

I am not able to figure out why "YearlyIncome" is all zero which is causing "Savings" to be all negative. What am I doing wrong and how do I calculate the "Savings" for each year?
I am running Python 3.10.12 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with Sqlite3
